# Number of nodes in Hartree-Fock solution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, computational-physics, orbitals

The Hartree-Fock equation for atoms  is of the form

$\left[\frac{d}{dr^2}+f(r)-\epsilon\right]P(r)=g(r) \tag1$

Usually algorithms to solve this equation assumes that the number of nodes of $P(r)$, $n_r$, is of the form
$$n_r=n-\ell-1 \tag2$$

where $\ell$ is the orbital quantum number and $n$ the principal quantum number.
For closed shell $(1)$ is spherical symmetric so $(2)$ is justified.

What about non-closed shell, what is the theoretical justification for  $(2)$?

Answer (score 0):

For non-closed shell calculations neither Eq. 1 nor Eq. 2 are theoretically justified. These equations are only valid for closed shell situations where spherical symmetry pertains.  This approach is called restricted Hartree-Fock.  See [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70643/whats-the-difference-between-rhf-and-uhf) from the Chemistry Stack Exchange for a discussion of more sophisticated methods.

Answer (score 0):

The Hartree-Fock equation has the form of Eq.1 when to derived it, you use basis of the form $\Psi=P_{lm}(r)Y(\theta,\phi)$ where $P_{lm}(r)$  are solution of a spherical potential, that is Eq.2 is imposed.